# Given x[u,v], y[u,v], and f[x,y] how do I find D[f,x] in terms of u,v?

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

I have two functions *x = x(u,v)* and *y = y(u,v)*. The chain rule says that for a function f(x,y), *df/dx = df/du du/dx + df/dv dv/dx*, and similarly *df/dy = df/du du/dy + df/dv dv/dy*.

How do I get *Mathematica* to give me *df/dx* in terms of *u*, *v*, and *df/du*, *df/dv*?

I should point out that *x(u,v)* and *y(u,v)* are **not** easily invertible to give *u(x,y)* and *v(x,y)*.

Answer (score 4):

You need to solve the linear system
$$\begin{align}
{\partial f \over \partial u}& = {\partial f \over \partial x} {\partial x \over \partial u} + {\partial f \over \partial y} {\partial y \over \partial u} \\
{\partial f \over \partial v}& = {\partial f \over \partial x} {\partial x \over \partial v} + {\partial f \over \partial y} {\partial y \over \partial v} \\
\end{align}$$
which can be done in *Mathematica* like this:

```
Solve[D[f[x[u, v], y[u, v]], {{u, v}}] == {dfdu[u, v], dfdv[u, v]},
   {Derivative[1, 0][f][x[u, v], y[u, v]], Derivative[0, 1][f][x[u, v], y[u, v]]}]
```

Here ${\partial f / \partial u}$, ${\partial f /\partial v}$ are represented by `dfdu` and `dfdv`.  One problem with Leibniz' notation is that symbols are treated simultaneously as variables and as functions, which I've found difficult to do in programs like *Mathematica*.  It's best to do it all in terms of functions in this case.  For instance, `Derivative[1, 0][f]` represents ${\partial f / \partial x}$.  However, in the expression ${\partial f / \partial u}$, $f$ represents the composition of $f(x,y)$ with $x(u,v)$ and $y(u,v)$, and the partial derivative is a derivative of the composition. In *Mathematica* you do that explicitly: compose the functions and differentiate.  The system solved by `Solve` above is the same as

```
D[f[x[u, v], y[u, v]], u] == dfdu[u, v]
D[f[x[u, v], y[u, v]], v] == dfdv[u, v]
```

which makes `dfdu`, `dfdv` equivalent to the partial derivatives with respect to `u`, `v`.  The output is a bit messy:

[image: System solution]

If you like you can clean up the look by using `Format` to make *Mathematica* write in the output in Leibniz' notation - if you really want to see the output in that sort of form.  (Beware: Using `Format` this way can get you confused if your intention is to continue working with the output.  At least it can get me confused.)

```
Format[Derivative[1, 0][f][args__]] := Row[{"\[PartialD]", f}]/Row[{"\[PartialD]", x}]; 
Format[Derivative[0, 1][f][args__]] := Row[{"\[PartialD]", f}]/Row[{"\[PartialD]", y}]; 
Format[dfdu[args__]] := Row[{"\[PartialD]", f}]/Row[{"\[PartialD]", u}]; 
Format[dfdv[args__]] := Row[{"\[PartialD]", f}]/Row[{"\[PartialD]", v}]; 
Format[Derivative[1, 0][g : x | y][args__]] := Row[{"\[PartialD]", g}]/Row[{"\[PartialD]", u}];
Format[Derivative[0, 1][g : x | y][args__]] := Row[{"\[PartialD]", g}]/Row[{"\[PartialD]", v}];

Solve[D[f[x[u, v], y[u, v]], {{u, v}}] == {dfdu[u, v], dfdv[u, v]},
   {Derivative[1, 0][f][x[u, v], y[u, v]], Derivative[0, 1][f][x[u, v], y[u, v]]}]
```

[image: Formatted output]