# Why is the difference in the behavior of Solve?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

Solving in 13.2.1 on Windows 10

```
Solve[Log[a] + Log[b] == 2 && 1/Log[a] + 1/Log[b] == 3, {Log[a],Log[b]}]
```

, I obtain

> `{{Log[a] -> 1/3 (3 - Sqrt[3]),  Log[b] -> 1/3 (3 + Sqrt[3])}, {Log[a] -> 1/3 (3 + Sqrt[3]),  Log[b] -> 1/3 (3 - Sqrt[3])}}`

, but

```
Solve[Tan[a] + Tan[b] == 2 && 1/Tan[a] + 1/Tan[b] == 3, {Tan[a],Tan[b]}]
```

> `{}`

and

```
Reduce[Tan[a] + Tan[b] == 2 && 1/Tan[a] + 1/Tan[b] == 3, {Tan[a], Tan[b]}]
```

> `Cot[a] == 3 - Cot[b] && Tan[b] == 2 - Tan[a]`

The question arises: why `Solve` and `Reduce` badly handle it?

Addition.[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18809/given-xu-v-yu-v-and-fx-y-how-do-i-find-df-x-in-terms-of-u-v/18838#18838) is an example of such type question, where unknowns are functions.

Comment: To confirm, the “bugs” tag is not appropriate for this thread.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Why do you think so? Let us call things by their proper names.

Comment: You don't have a good track record in this arena. Sorry. As for the design decisions of what to allow or not allow for `Solve` variable names, they remains in flux. This won't tip the needle though.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau:  I prefer arguments over emotional words. The `Solve` command in the question produces a wrong result `{}` without any warning.

Comment: One argument is that you've filed a few hundred bug reports, virtually none of which have anything beyond middle priority, with the majority being lower. So there is reason based on long-standing evidence to not take seriously an assertion on your part that something like this is a bug.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: Do you find the `{}` result of `Solve` in the question correct? I recovered the tag.

Comment: Yes, I think it's correct for the way Solve works. Solve looks for explicit occurrences of `f[x]` when you use compound solution variables and in your case `1/Tan[a]` evaluates away. That's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: The result is wrong. No warning/error is performed. That's all.

Comment: Please read the documentation for [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) carefully and thouroughly, and show us an example where `Log[a]` or `Tan[a]` or anything else than a _pure symbol_ (like `x` or `y`) is used as `vars` in the second argument. There is no example of such usage. Therefore, it is not the result that is wrong, you are using `Solve` wrongly. Just because it somehow happens to work for `Log[a]`, there is no guarantee it will work for `Tan[a]` because this is not a documented feature.

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18809/given-xu-v-yu-v-and-fx-y-how-do-i-find-df-x-in-terms-of-u-v/18838#18838) is an example of such  a type question.

Comment: You're basically asking `a` and `b` to treated like indices instead of variables. And you're asking `f[a]` and `f[b]` to be treated as independent variables, not functions for `f = Log` and `f = Tan`; and thus in the `Tan` case, the reciprocal expressions `Cot[a]` and `Cot[b]` are not treated as functions of `a` and `b` but as independent parameters. All of this is because you asked `Solve` to behave that way. Your code is more like `Solve[f[a]+[b] == 2 && g[a]+g[b] == 3, {f[a], f[b]}]` or
`Solve[x+y == 2 && w+z == 3, {x, y}]`, in which the parametric condition `w+z == 3` is generically false

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `Trace[Solve[...], TraceInternal -> True]` to observe the difference between cases with `Tan` and `Log`. You will see that `1/Tan[a]` gets converted to `Cot[a]` before any solving methods are applied while `1/Log[a]` remains intact.

Use `SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False]` to prevent this and get the results.

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False];

Solve[Tan[a] + Tan[b] == 2 && 1/Tan[a] + 1/Tan[b] == 3, {Tan[a],Tan[b]}]

(* {{Tan[a] -> 1/3 (3 - Sqrt[3]), Tan[b] -> 1/3 (3 + Sqrt[3])}, 
    {Tan[a] -> 1/3 (3 + Sqrt[3]), Tan[b] -> 1/3 (3 - Sqrt[3])}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you. Therefore, this is an unfinished work of Mathematica developers.